# Show elipses where text will be truncated as per iTunes

Tags: wpf, xaml

I a building an application with a similar layout to iTunes i.e. it has a sidebar that doubles as a menu.  Some of the text will exceed the boundary and rather that having it be truncated I would like to show ellipses (see line image below "Purchased on My iPh...").

[iTunes http://www.gumpshen.com/images/temp/ituneselipses.jpg](http://www.gumpshen.com/images/temp/ituneselipses.jpg)

How would I go about this in WPF?

Suppose I made the boundary movable i.e. user can change the size of the panel (split panel in Windows Forms), how would I go about dynamically showing the ellipses/text?

Thanks in advance,

B

Answer (score 3):

TextBlock has a property called "TextTrimming" and you can set Ellipsis enum there.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding YourTextproperty}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipis" .../>
```